# What test of difference would I need to run!

Tags: t-test

I’m creating a research proposal poster in which I’m looking at if a reading scheme increases intrinsic motivations to read.

I’ve chosen a sample of participants with half taking part in the scheme, and half being the control group who dont take part. All participants will complete a reading questionnaire at two points in time to see if motivation scores change.

Would this be a 2x2 mixed design, and if so can i run an independent t-test to investigate this?
I’m inexperienced with statistics so any help would be appreciated!